# Firebase one to one chat implementation for web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, chat, private

I implemented friendly chat. But that is group chat. I am new to firebase. Need docs for creating one to one web chat. How to get list of user accounts and selecting single user to send message? Please help me

Comment: do you ever read this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: yes but fire base cloud messaging (FCM) used for push notification to multiple devices.

If FCM can do chat application like facebook messgener.Then how ??

Comment: Are you able to implement it ?

Comment: Yes I Implemented long back ago !.

Answer (score 3):

If the users communicating have user IDs uid_1 and uid_2.

The database structure should be:

```
contacts
   --uid1
       --uid2
       --uid3
       -- so on (1)
   --uid2
       --uid1
       --uid4
       -- so on (2)
messages
   --uid1
       --uid2
           -- Push messages here.(3)
   --uid2
       --uid3
           -- Push messages here also.(4)
```

#### Adding Contacts

If USER 1 knows USER 2 you can add USER 2 in location (1) and add USER 1 in location (2). Since you are implementing with user IDs the USERS will be able to send messages if they know the other USER's uid. You can send Chat Invites to exchange uids.

#### Adding Messages

If USER 1 or USER 2 sends a message add at locations (3) and (4). This implementation will make sure that even if USER 1 deletes a conversation with USER 2, USER 2 will still have a copy and thus ensuring privacy.

These are the key elements to make a basic one-on-one Firebase Chat App.

NOTE: User IDs are provided by Firebase on successful authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try breaking your problem into individual milestones and learn how Firebase works as you need help in each milestone.

According to what you have written, you have to:

- Authenticate Users (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)
- Save those user profiles onto the Real-Time Firebase Database in the following data structure (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)
- List those users in a List / RecycleView (learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-recycleradapter)
- Manage the conversation through listeners in the adapter that reference child nodes which serve as rooms between 2 people.

Think about how to make your structure as efficient as possible such as not saving conversations twice under each user but rather saving a reference to a separate 'conversations' node.

I recently implemented this in my location-based app (Occupapp) if you want a live example. You will have to register, add a service and log in from another device and select that service to chat to the owner.